# ngAnimate $$animateJs is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Help again...

i'm trying to use ui-bootstrap, but modals did not animate, so I tried including ngAnimate, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: $$animateJs is not a function
    at prepareAnimation (angular-animate.js:2042)
    at initDriverFn (angular-animate.js:2032)
    at invokeFirstDriver (angular-animate.js:3070)
    at Array.triggerAnimationStart (angular-animate.js:2916)
    at nextTick (angular-animate.js:416)
    at scheduler (angular-animate.js:386)
    at angular-animate.js:2938
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16145)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16359)
    at done (angular.js:10791)
```

this is my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "sb-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "appPath": "app",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.16",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.1.0",
    "metisMenu": "~2.2.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.8.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.5.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.22",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "oclazyload": "ocLazyLoad#~1.0.9",
    "lodash": "~4.0.1",
    "angular-smart-table": "~2.1.6",
    "angular-google-maps": "~2.3.0",
    "angular-simple-logger": "~0.1.5",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-animate": "1.4.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.1.0",
    "angular": ">=1.2.0",
    "lodash": "~4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Some ideas?

Comment: try more current version ....  looks pretty old

Comment: what is old? isn't 1.4.9 the last stable version?

Comment: no..the problem one ..ui-bootstrap.

Comment: I run into the same issue! It happens only when I use ui.router configurations with angular animate 1.4.9. Did anything worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, taking a look at the documentation (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) I saw this:

*Angular Requirements*

*UI Bootstrap 1.0 and higher requires Angular 1.4.x or higher and it has been tested with Angular 1.4.8.*

So I downgroaded the angular version to 1.4.8 in my "bower.json" file and now I don't get the error message anymore.